# Video Capture using Callback showing error on orientation changed

Tags: android

I have created an app which works like this, it asks the user to select a video either he can do it by selecting from gallery or capturing video at that time only .

for this I have written my code like this :-

```
public class VideoQuestionActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, Callback
{
 / Here I have declared my object like Button etc so omitting this from code / 

 private Dialog myDialog;
 private Dialog videoDialog;


 private File videoFolder;
 private String videoFileName;
 private String selectedVideoPath;
 private Uri selectedVideoURI;
 private Bitmap bMap;  

 private SurfaceView surfaceView;
 private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
 private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question);


    mCurrentSurvey =(Survey)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("CurrentSurvey");
    mCurrentQuestion =(Question)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("CurrentQuestion");

    Initialize();
}

public void Initialize()
  {
    // This function initializes the objects like buttons, surface view media player so also omitting this just to keep the code simple
  }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId())
    {

        case R.id.btnQuestionTypeAction:
            getVideo();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_live:
            Intent liveIntent= new Intent(  android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(liveIntent,RESULT_CAPTURE_VIDEO);
            myDialog.dismiss();
            break;

        case R.id.btn_gallery:
            Intent galIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            galIntent.setType("video/*");
            startActivityForResult(galIntent,RESULT_LOAD_VIDEO);
            myDialog.dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.btnCancel:
            videoDialog.dismiss();
            break;

        case R.id.btnOk:
            videoDialog.dismiss();
            boolean sdcardAvailable = sdcardState();
            if(sdcardAvailable)
            {

            videoFolder =new File(userFolderPath+"/Videos");
            if(!videoFolder.exists())
            {
                videoFolder.mkdir();
            }

            CopyFile(selectedVideoPath,videoFolder.toString());

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), selectedVideoURI);
                mediaPlayer.prepare(); 
                mediaPlayer.start();

            } 
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (SecurityException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IllegalStateException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selectedVideoPath , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SD Card not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}

public void startIntentForController()
{
    // this function calls another activity so omitting this from code. 
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {



}

private void getVideo() 
{
    boolean sdcardAvailable = sdcardState();
    if(sdcardAvailable)
    {
        extStorageDirectory= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
        userFolderPath=extStorageDirectory+"/User";
        File userFolder=new File(userFolderPath);
        if(!(userFolder.exists()))
            userFolder.mkdir();
        dialogShow();
    }
    else
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("SD Card unavailable.....")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}

public boolean sdcardState()
{
    sdcardState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(sdcardState)) 
    {
        // We can read and write the media
        return true;
    } 
    else    
    {
        // We can't read and write the media
        return false;
    }  
}
public void dialogShow()
{
    myDialog = new Dialog(VideoQuestionActivity.this);
    myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.picturecustomdialog);

    //Initializing the UI component of custom dialog 
    TextView title = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.lbl_photo);
    TextView subTitle = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.lbl_source);
    Button gallery=(Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_gallery);
    Button live=(Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_live);

    //Setting the value to each UI component of custom dialog
    title.setText("Attach a Video");
    subTitle.setText("Choose a source");
    gallery.setText("Gallery");
    live.setText("Capture");

    myDialog.show();
    gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
    live.setOnClickListener(this);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{ 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) 
    {

        myDialog.dismiss();
        Uri myVideo;
        myVideo= data.getData();    
        selectedVideoURI=myVideo;
        selectedVideoPath= getRealPathFromURI(myVideo);
        videoDialogshow();

    }

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && data!= null) 
    {
        finish();
    }

    if (requestCode == RESULT_CAPTURE_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    {


        myDialog.dismiss();
        Uri myVideo;
        myVideo= data.getData();
        selectedVideoURI=myVideo;   
        selectedVideoPath= (getRealPathFromURI(myVideo));
        videoDialogshow();
    }

    if (requestCode == RESULT_CAPTURE_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED ) 
    {
        finish();
    }
    if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED)
    {
        mCurrentSurvey.setSurveyQuestionIndex(mCurrentSurvey.getSurveyQuestionIndex());
        startIntentForController();
    }
}


public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) 
{
    String imgAbsolutePath;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    imgAbsolutePath=cursor.getString(column_index);
    return imgAbsolutePath;
}

public void videoDialogshow()
{
    videoDialog = new Dialog(VideoQuestionActivity.this);
    videoDialog.setContentView(R.layout.mediacontaincustomdialog);

    //Initializing the UI component of custom dialog 
    Button btnVideoCancel = (Button) videoDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    Button btnVideoOk = (Button) videoDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    btnVideoCancel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_wrong);
    btnVideoOk.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_right);

    //Setting the value to each UI component of custom dialog
    LinearLayout llMediaView =(LinearLayout) videoDialog.findViewById(R.id.llMediaView);
    final VideoView mediaVideoView=new VideoView(this);

    mediaVideoView.setVideoURI(selectedVideoURI);
    mediaVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mediaVideoView.requestFocus();
    llMediaView.addView(mediaVideoView);
    videoDialog.show();

    bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(selectedVideoPath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
    mediaVideoView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bMap));
    mediaVideoView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mediaVideoView.start();
        }
    }); 

    btnVideoCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnVideoOk.setOnClickListener(this);
}



public boolean CopyFile(String srcPath,String destPath)
{
    //this function copies the file to a custom location in my sd card so also omitting this
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mediaPlayer.reset();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    mediaPlayer.release();
}
}
```

Now this code works fine on my phone, but whenever I change the orientation then my application crashes.

Also In my manifest I have added the config changes attribute i.e :-

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

, i m putting my logcat ,

```
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907): java.lang.IllegalStateException
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native Method)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.reset(MediaPlayer.java:1066)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.optimus.mobile.question.VideoQuestionActivity.surfaceDestroyed(VideoQuestionActivity.java:475)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.SurfaceView.reportSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceView.java:568)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:472)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:206)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:6173)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1156)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRoot.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRoot.java:1630)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRoot.doDie(ViewRoot.java:2671)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.ViewRoot.die(ViewRoot.java:2641)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:218)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeViewImmediate(Window.java:436)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3684)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3789)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2037)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-05 20:26:09.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1907):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any thoughts on How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an onConfigurationChanged() method. So that it automatically saves to app's current progress and remains running when it switches between orientations.

This link might help you a little more with your problem. It worked for me when I was having the same problem.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: I tried that  but still the problem persists , may be I m missing some action that has to be written in this method?